# SQL Exception(sql Code)(sqlState 42883 ) thrown due to ERROR :operator does not exist: character varying + unknown

Tags: postgresql

I am getting this error in postgres query. i have tried typecasting so that the + operator would work on similar errors but how do i search for unknown. what does unknown represent and how do i search for it

Comment: The string [concatenation operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) in SQL is `||` - the `+` is used to add numbers

Comment: And the query is?